# Meaning of "They say! What say they? Let them say."

Tags: phrase-meaning, popular-refrains

I've heard this quote in the past, but have never really found any reference to the meaning of it. "They say! What say they? Let them say." was the personal motto of reclusive millionaire Edward F. Searles.

Comment: The second sentence is very awkward; I'm surprised it was a native speaker's motto.

Comment: Hadn't heard of it, but I would assume it means something like: "(So) they talk (about me)? What (do) they say? Let them talk.", or in short: "I don't care what they say about me."

Comment: "What say they" is certainly not modern usage, but isn't unrecognizable. "What say you?" is a (still antiquated) phrase that I've also heard.

Comment: Yes, @BradC, the pattern "What V S?" is characteristic of EModE, as opposed to PDE's "What do[es] S V?"

Comment: What say you? Is very common although old-fashioned. That said, it then allows for What say they?

Comment: @DanBron That's odd. The second sentence is the only one that sounds normal (if old-style) to me. “They say!” and “Let them say!” are _extremely_ bizarre to me: _say_ is mandatorily transitive in my world, and no object can be inferred from the quote given here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be in response to a reproach grounded in folk wisdom or popular opinion—perhaps interrupting the reproach after just two words, the two spat back at the beginning of this “motto.” To paraphrase:

> You throw popular opinion in my face? What is that popular opinion? No, never mind—let the great mass of fools say whatever they will.

Answer (score 3):

SUPPLEMENTAL to Brian Donovan's ANSWER:

The slogan was well known in the later 19th and early 20th century: Lily Langtry, for instance, is said to have had it either carved over her mantle or displayed in stained glass in the house the Prince of Wales built for her, and Bernard Shaw found it carved over the mantle of the house he bought in Adelphi Terrace.

The unusual syntax may be attributed to an origin in Renaissance Scots; it appears to have been originally the motto of Marischal College in Aberdeen, founded by the Earl Marischal of Scotland George Keith in 1593. A number of internet sources cite the oldest version as *THAI HAIF SAID : QUHAT SAY THAY : LAT THAME SAY*. But the earliest actual citation I have found is from 1824, in one of John MacCulloch's 'letters' to Walter Scott in *The Highlands and Western Isles...*.

There are several posts in *Notes & Queries* claiming classical precedents, Latin (*Aiunt. Quid aiunt? Aiant.*) and Greek (λέγουσιν  ἄ θέγουσιν λεγέτωσαν), and Keith was said to be a fine scholar in these languages.

Comment: +1, but λέγουσιν; ἃ θέλουσι λεγέτωσαν seems more likely. ("They say? Let them say what they wish.")

Comment: The St. Andrews Citizen - Saturday 09 March 1935 - reports on a door lintel being removed from a ruined historic cottage in St Andrews (Fife, Scotland). The lintel had an inscription and a date: 'They have said, and they will say; Let them be saying 1720'
The lintel was moved in 1935 to the doorway to Dyers Brae garden wher it still is.

Comment: According to Consuelo Vanderbilt, who married the 9th Duke of Marlborough, it is carved into a mantle piece in a bedroom at Blenheim Palace. She wrote about it in 'The Glitter and the Gold'

Comment: I couldn't edit that, only 4 mins ago. Correction:  It's mentioned in Caroline Davison's 2022 book "The Captain's Apprentice " page 285 as the Pioneer Club motto of Emily Massingberd  around 1878.

Answer (score 0):

"They Say"-The people will always have opinions, advise and suggestions for you.

"What Say They?"- In a way it means, how does it matter what they say? (its your life, your decision you are the actor) and also it could imply what say do they have in your life(authority to speak about someone else's life)

"Let them say"- They will always say...you cannot stop them. So let them say. To take or leave is entirely your decision.

Comment: This seems to repeat the responses of two other users without adding any particular value.

Answer (score 0):

It's origins are Scottish -- Thay Haif Said: Quhat Say Thay? Lat Thame Say -- and date back to Clan Keith in the 16th Century

If you want to learn more, there is an interesting article here: http://rdhardesty.blogspot.com/2014/03/say.html

Comment: Is this your own article?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this in a book by the once-famous Liberal journalist AG Gardiner. I loved the musicality of it and, in checking if it was original to Gardiner, found myself here: five years late!

[Prophets, Priests and Kings](https://archive.org/details/prophetspriests00gardiala/page/92/mode/2up?q=%22They%20say%22) (1908) is the book, a collection of biographical sketches on all sorts of contemporaries (this quote, 'Say, what say they, let them say' was from the one about Sir Edward Grey). If may add: Gardiner's prose fair sparkles and I had some feeling of awe and era-admiration as when stumbled on Lytton Strachey. We might be able to do transplants nowadays, women vote, perhaps other things are better, but I no longer assume that we, as a rule, necessarily write better. Only my ignorance made me think it so.

Comment: It's there but it's not older than the 1824 source mentioned in [StoneyB's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/363718/191178)